# Editar arquivo texto em uma linha especifica

Tags: c#, winforms, txt

Tenho um arquivo txt que me informa 3 campos: linha do erro, numero errado e numero para substituir.

Porém não estou pensando numa instrução para ir diretamente na linha que preciso, esse arquivo segue um layout.

Posso colocar aqui os exemplos, se quiser.

https://pastebin.com/5eDHQcgX <- ARQUIVO EM QUE QUERO FAZER AS MODIFICACOES
https://pastebin.com/xKkJjyds <- ARQUIVO COM AS LINHAS E VALORES A SUBSTITUIR

Forma que estou capturando meu txt.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            selecionaArquivo();
        }
        public void selecionaArquivo()
        {
            try
            {
                if (abrirArquivo.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    speed = new StreamReader(abrirArquivo.FileName);
                    MessageBox.Show("Arquivo importado");
                }
```

Comment: Ponha um exemplo do arquivo pode ajudar na compreensão do que você deseja.

Comment: Por exemplo  Na linha 125479 desse meu arquivo  tem C425|1033395|4,000|CX|11,96|0,20|0,91| E eu desejo substituir o valor 11,96 por 12,15 E eu ja tenho um arquivo com esses "logs" de erro. 125479|11,96|12,15, onde, em ordem é: linha onde está o errado, dado a ser substituido, dado a ser inserido no lugar

Comment: @wesley o link que você postou na pergunta, não existe a linha 125479.

Comment: Ah sim, foi só um exemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de seguir o código, você tem que saber qual a linha quer editar, no exemplo abaixo coloquei na linha **1**:

```
 int line_to_edit = 1; //linha 1
 string newText = "|C425|1033395|4,000|CX|12,15|0,20|0,91|";
 string path = "colocar o caminho do arquivo";
 string[] arrLine = File.ReadAllLines(path);
 arrLine[line_to_edit - 1] = newText;
 File.WriteAllLines(path, arrLine);
```

Resposta original: [StackOverFlow Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35496185/6647038)

**Update:**

```
//arquivo logs
string[] logs = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\logs.txt");

//arquivo para modificar
string path = @"C:\modificar.txt";
string[] arrLine = File.ReadAllLines(path);

foreach (var item in logs)
{
    //split[0] = LINHA
    //split[1] = VALOR ERRADO
    //split[2] = VALOR A SUBSTITUIR
    var split = item.Split('|');
    int line_to_edit = Convert.ToInt32(split[0]);
    var replace = arrLine[line_to_edit - 1].Replace(split[1], split[2]);
    string newText = replace;
    arrLine[line_to_edit - 1] = newText;
    File.WriteAllLines(path, arrLine);
}
```

Comment: Entao, no caso eu to fazendo uma aplicação pro contabil. To fazendo com windows form, tem alguma função em C# que le todas as linhas ? Porque readallines no c# nao ta rodando, e readline lê linha a linha.

Comment: @wesley Como assim "readallines no c# nao ta rodando" ?

Comment: @wesley `ReadAllLines` lê todas a linhas dele e retorna array string na variável arrLine.

Comment: Bom quando eu coloco pra chamar a funcao ReadAllLines pro meu objeto streamer, nao funciona. OBS: To usando o open filedialog pra procurar o arquivo que preciso

Comment: @wesley O que você está tentando fazer ? Me explique melhor, para eu poder te ajudar. Não estou  entendendo.

Comment: Desculpe se nao estou sendo claro. Dois dois arquivos txt para relatorio fiscal, um onde ele me informa, linha onde está um dado errado, o valor errado, e o valor a ser reposto. Preciso entrar com esses dois arquivos, e linha a linha buscar esses dados errado e repor com o valor certo. Por exemplo Na linha 125479 desse meu arquivo tem C425|1033395|4,000|CX|11,96|0,20|0,91| E eu desejo substituir o valor 11,96 por 12,15 E eu ja tenho um arquivo com esses "logs" de erro. 125479|11,96|12,15, onde, em ordem é: linha onde está o errado, dado a ser substituido, dado a ser inserido no lugar (Copia)

Comment: @wesley esse link:https://pastebin.com/5eDHQcgX tem na linha 539 é isso mesmo ?

Comment: Isso mesmo, Hoje isso é feito na mao, estou criando essa rotina para optimizar o trabalho.

Comment: Pois nao, Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: @wesley editei a resposta veja se funciona.

Comment: Assim está funcinando perfeitamente! Porém, eu estou fazendo com o forms, pro usuario abrir os dois arquivos, como fazer essa modificação ?

Comment: Aí você tem que fazer outra pergunta aqui no stackoverflow

Comment: Perfeito, amanha irei fazer isso. Muitissimo Obrigado!